# how to address nested ULs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem rewriting all anchors in a page when it comes to a nested `<ul>`.

We have issues in Chrome using `<a>` (anchors) so I am rewriting the anchors to be `<span>`s with click handlers on them.
Everything works except: where a nested `<ul>` begins, the `<li>` that precedes it, (the unclosed `<li>`), ends up at the end of the nested list rather than at the beginning.

Any thoughts?
*(this needs to work across hundreds of pages, so a one-off is not really a solution)*

```
function see() {

  var lists=document.getElementsByTagName('LI');  //all li

  for (var i=0; i<lists.length; i++) {
    var hrf0=lists[i].innerHTML;

     if (lists[i].childNodes.length>0  && hrf0.indexOf('#')!=-1) {

        var testnode0=lists[i].innerHTML;
        var testnode=lists[i].children[0].innerHTML;
        var testnode2=testnode.trim();
        var firstchar = testnode0.charAt(0);

        if (firstchar=='<' && testnode0.search('http://')<0 ) {
              var linktext=lists[i].children[0].innerHTML;
              var hrf3=lists[i].children[0].href;
              var hrf2=hrf3.split('#')[1];   //target

              lists[i].removeChild(lists[i].children[0]);   //remove a

              var para = document.createElement('span');
              lists[i].appendChild(para); 
              var newlinktext = document.createTextNode(linktext);
              lists[i].children[0].appendChild(newlinktext);
              lists[i].children[0].setAttribute("id", "a" + i);
              lists[i].children[0].setAttribute("data-link", hrf2);
              lists[i].children[0].setAttribute("class", 'newanchor');
              lists[i].children[0].style.cursor="pointer";

              document.getElementById('a' + i).addEventListener('click',   gothere, false);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the linking code (but it works):

```
function gothere() {
   var link=this.getAttribute('data-link');
   var element = document.getElementById(link);
   element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: If you could provide HTML and a snippet so we can see it in action, that would help

Comment: I apologize for not directly addressing the question, but why would you  need to change the elements for chrome?  What bug is causing you to need to do this?  Have you posted a question elsewhere on SO addressing the issue in chrome?

Comment: we have a documentation site that uses frames and we cant chnge that. once in a frame, the anchors do not work in chrome.

Comment: ill make a fiddle. will take a few mins

Comment: here is a jsbin. now you have to click the see links link a bunch of times for the function to run. but that is not the case in my page. in the real code it is wrapped in a document.onload function instead.  http://jsbin.com/soxoyicazi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Nancymic Even with `target="_top"`?

Comment: omg no it jumps out of the frame but guess what, target="_self" works to keep it in the frame. Hello 1996!! Guess javascript was my hammer. Thanks. Brilliant!!!